# Plotting primary and secondary axis with lines and confidence intervals in R ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, line, axis, yaxis

I am trying to plot two y-axis (Number, Size) with a single x-axis (density). I want to plot only the means of the data points and a bootstrapped confidence interval with lines connecting the means. Here is my code

```
density <- c("1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1", "2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","3","3","3","3","3","3","3","3","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4")

var <- c(3,4,5,1,6,7,3,2,6,2,5,3,4,5,1,2,7,8,2,3,4,5,4,7,8,1,1,2,3,4,2,5)

z <- c("Number","Number","Number","Number","Size","Size","Size","Size","Number","Number","Number","Number","Size","Size","Size","Size","Number","Number","Number","Number","Size","Size","Size","Size","Number","Number","Number","Number","Size","Size","Size","Size")

d4 <- data.frame(density, var,z)

mycolors <- c("Number"="#F8766D", "Size" = "#F8766D")


library(ggplot2)
ggplot(d4, aes(x= density, y= var, group = z, color = z)) +
  geom_path() +
  stat_summary(fun.data=mean_cl_boot, geom="errorbar", width=0.2, colour="gray") + stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point", pch=21, size=3) +
  scale_y_continuous(name="log(Number)", sec.axis = sec_axis(~ 2*., name="Size")) +
  scale_color_manual(name="z", values = mycolors)
```

[image]

I face two problems: 
a) The size column is taking up much higher values than given in the dataset. 
The mean values that are expected are:

```
 Number Size
1   3.25  4.5
2   4.00  3.0
3   5.00  5.0
4   3.00  3.5
```

b) The means of the 'number' and 'size' are not joining together correctly

Also,is there a way to specify a solid line with solid dots for the "number" column and dashed line with triangle dots for the 'size' column

Comment: For the first problem, why not giving the secondary axis the same scale as the first one, given that values are in the same range?

Comment: Yes! My bad. I can correct that